# debug lag of calculate margin top for Position fixed sidebar scrolling to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I want to fix left sidebar on the responsive view.

I use Margin top (dependency with scroll position) for wrapper of sidebar!
that's work! but on the some browser it's slow motion  (example: macbook pro retina 15" 2014 chrome Version 42)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp3bn5yy/1/)

```
 jQuery(function($){
    var target = $('#fixed_sidebar .fixed');
    var sidebarPosition = $(target).offset().top;

    function calculatesidebar(){
        var  heightWindow = $(window).height();
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        var sidebarHeight = target.outerHeight();
        var positionOftarget = (sidebarPosition + sidebarHeight) - heightWindow;
        var targetMargin =  parseInt(target.css('marginTop'));


        if (scrollPosition >= positionOftarget){
            var margin = scrollPosition - positionOftarget;
            target.css('marginTop', margin+'px');

        }else{
            target.css('marginTop', '0');
        }

    }

    $( window ).scroll(function(){
        calculatesidebar();
    });
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        calculatesidebar();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm resolved in other way

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp3bn5yy/2/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {


    function fixed_sidebar_bottom(wrapper, target) {
        var left = $(wrapper).offset().left,
            right = $(wrapper).offset().right,
            top = $(wrapper).offset().top,
            width = $(wrapper).width(),
            target = $(target),
            targetHeight = target.outerHeight(),
            scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height(),
            windowWidth = $(window).width(),
            hotSpot = (top + targetHeight) - windowHeight;


            if (scrollPosition >= hotSpot) {

                if (!target.attr('style')) {
                    target.css({'left': left, 'right': right, 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '0', 'width': width});
                } else {
                    target.css({'left': left, 'right': right, 'width': width});
                }
            } else {
                target.removeAttr("style");
            }
        }





    $(window).scroll(function () {
        fixed_sidebar_bottom('#fixed_sidebarLeft','#fixed_sidebarLeft_target');    
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        fixed_sidebar_bottom('#fixed_sidebarLeft','#fixed_sidebarLeft_target'); 
    });
});
```